# Website administration - Integrated into main website or separate section?

Tags: security, usability, administration

From a usability perspective, is it better to integrate admin section on the main website or have a separate section to manage content?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the application is a CMS for very non-techno friendly staff.

Comment: I would add security and administration as tags

Comment: I see most people are ignoring your first 4 words and focusing on security issues.. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the project and part you want to administer, imho.

For example comments on newsposts should be administered in the website itself by showing a "delete" linkbutton for each comment. Otherwise the mods would have to look up the comment in the admin section => not very user friendly.

But in general I think a seperate admin section will usually be more clear to your client. You'd want them to see the site as a normal user would see it.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least I would recommend moving all your administration files to a separate folder.  That way if you're using a platform like .NET you can very easily control folder access though role and user-based web.config permissions.

Having your administration files all segregated allows you to do other things easily too, like delete them if you decide to move them to another server later.  Also you can exclude them in your robots.txt file (although by putting it in the robots.txt file you will be telling other people this section exists, and robots don't have to mind this file).

Edit:

I feel like my answer missed the mark a little considering your question.  Of course in-line editing is easier than going to a separate page from a usability perspective, but whenever I hear of mixing admin users with regular users giant alarm bells go off in my head.

I think that it depends on the function of the site and how intrusive it will be to your staff.  Does it make sense for them to make changes while browsing the site and will they eventually become discouraged with your system because it forces them to inject unnecessary steps into their process?  How long will the edits take?  Does it make sense to show a completely different interface to administrators?  I think an answer to this question requires a lot more understanding of what specific function you're trying to accomplish and will vary on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2):

I have never liked adding administration pages into the main site.  It seems like it is too much of a risk from someone accidently getting access to the administration portion of the site.  Even if you review the security over and over, there is always that possibility that something unexpected will happen, and it is a huge mess to clean up (what was modified, who accessed what etc. etc.).  In my opinion keeping it as a seperate site is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a level of convenience in being able to login to the main part of a site as a privileged user, and then clicking on parts of a page to edit/alter it, there is also a measure of security in having it in a separate area.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that having a separate section of the website that is devoted specifically to administrative tasks makes the tasks easier to organize and use. Just look at Wordpress (especially the new 2.7 release), Drupal (a very popular cms), and Joomla (another very popular cms). If you would like to test these feature out to see why I think the separate section is better, you can go to [www.opensourcecms.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com) and test out both Drupal and Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

From a usability, the more integrated the better but it tends to add severely to the complexity. Its always best if you can perform the action within the context in which it occurs - lock out a bad user, trim a log thats too big etc. however since these tend to have significant side effects the security aspect trumps this a lot of the time out of fear.

I think you need to look at doing a risk assessment with regards to integrating the administration capabilities right into the application.

- What would be the implication for the system if someone were able to escalate privelages and gain access to the admin functions. if every user was locked out maliciously - damage to the site, the reputation, SLA etc?
- What destructive functions can an admin perform from this section ? delete lots of data? crash the app? alter costs that have material impact on users/customers?
- Are the admin functions integrated in the app or isolated into specific admin functions?
- Does the application have a public face or is it an intranet that is assumed secure?

I personally have never felt at ease integrating the admin section with the site out of fear that a security breach caused by my ineptness or something beyond my control like bad defaults, unpatched exploit. However, when the client is writing the cheque I tend to do what they feel is best.

Answer (score 1):

I come from the school of Usability that says "minimise guess work". So, what kind of information did you get from your user group sessions?

Remember, you're not (and we're not) typical users of your system. Anything we say is going to be a guess. What's worse is that any opinion shown here is likely to be ill informed for your situation (but probably awesome at what they do). The only way you'll have an informed opinion on what to do is by going out and asking your users in intelligent ways.

Because this is a security issue some of your user mix should be people who specialise in security. Just because it's easier to use doesn't mean it's the most appropriate.